# Split string with this regex: [\\dc]+

Tags: java, regex, string

it's a relatively easy java question with spliting.

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String[] tokens = "aa33aaca^aa".split("[\\dc]+");
        for (int i = 0; i < tokens.length; i++)
            System.out.println(tokens[i]);  }
}
```

I'm wondering why is the output of this code is

```
aa
aa
a^aa
```

how is the "[\\dc]+" working exactly?

Comment: I get how the third line of the output has been splited, due to the "c" but I'm confused with the other part :(

Comment: What is unclear? It does exactly what you ask it to do, if that is not what you expected, then please describe what you actually want to happen. And consider consulting the Java documentation on [`Pattern`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html)

Comment: It's an regexp, Will split by a delimiter that is a number, or c character. So it's matching 33 and c. That is why you are receiving 3 results: aa,aa, a^aa.

Answer (score 2):

This [regular expression](https://www.regular-expressions.info/shorthand.html) will split the test by any combination of digits and character `'c'` repeated at least once:

- `\\d` - any digit [0-9]
- `c` - character 'c'
- `[]+` - characters inside of this set can occur at least once

So your string will be split like this:

```
   1     2
aa[33]aa[c]a^aa
```

Split delimiters:

1. Digit releated 2 times.
2. Character `c`.

Comment: So does that mean that the expression "\\d" splits any numbers in a string?

Comment: wow apparently yes it does thanks a lot !!!

Answer (score 0):

Besides the excellent answers above, Note that, if you test `[\\dc]+` in an online regex tester,like [rubular](http://rubular.com/) or others,  this regex will not match `33` in `aa33aaca^aa`. And they will say that :  `\d is mapping to Any digit character(0-9)`.

The reason is that in `String.split()` we are take `String` as our parameters, so we need an additional `\` to form a `escape sequence` to let the `\d` take effect.